# How could you get if a table is autoincrement or not from the metadata of an sqlite table?

Tags: sqlite, metadata, auto-increment

In case you have several tables inside any sqlite database how could the get the information that they have an auto increment primary key or not?

For instance I am already aware that you could get some info concerning the columns of a table by simply querying this: `pragma table_info(tablename_in_here)`

It would be much better to get the auto increment column dynamically rather than setting up each corresponding model inside the source code with a boolean value.

Edit:
Let me use this table as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"name" TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

and this is the result table after executing `pragma table_info("test")`

```
cid | name | type    | notnull | dflt_value | pk
  0 |   id | INTEGER |       1 |       null |  1
  1 | name |    TEXT |       1 |       null |  0
```

As you can see there is no information whether the `id` column is autoincrement or not

Edit2:
I looking for a solution that involves sqlite directly through a statement.
Special situations where the `sqlite3` command in the terminal can be used to somehow parse the required information from inside are **not** acceptable. They do not work in situations where you are not allowed to execute commands in a terminal programmatically. Like in an Android app.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by autoincremented? `rowid` or really `AUTOINCREMENT` - http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html? @CL. answer already finds the alias for the `rowid` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoincrementing primary keys [must be declared](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or some equivalent, so you can use the `table_info` date to detect them.

A column is an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column if, in the [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) output,

- the `type` is `integer` or `INTEGER` or any other case-insensitive variant; and
- `pk` is set; and
- `pk` is not set for any other column.

---

To check whether the column definition includes the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, you have to look directly into the [sqlite_master](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master) table; SQLite has no other mechanism to access this information.
If this query returns a record, you have the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword somewhere in the table definition (which might return a wrong result if this word is commented out):

```
SELECT 1
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND name = 'tablename_in_here'
  AND sql LIKE '%AUTOINCREMENT%'
```

Comment: I think that something should be said about the distinct behavior the optional AUTOINCREMENT keywork implies - http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html.

Comment: @AlixAxel I don't get it. what do you mean by *something should be said*?

Comment: @GeorgePligor: (mobile) your table definition has a autoincrement keyword, however the definition CL provided is true for rowids but not necessarely true for true autoincremented columns. One implies one additional  table, the other doesnt

Comment: Read the link i shared for more details.

Comment: @AlixAxel The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword has a misleading name; it does not enable autoincrementing behaviour (this is already done with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`), but prevents reusing deleted IDs.

Comment: @GeorgePligor The `PRAGMA table_info` statement can be executed like any other SQL statement, and returns a table like a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output of `.schema`.  That will give you the sql commands as you used them to create your tables.  If autoincrement was declared, you will see it in the output.  This has the advantage that it will list all your tables too.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and only works through the sqlite in command line. I have not such an access nor can I execute terminal commands programmatically to get the result. In fact I would like this to be used in Android where all I can do is valid sql statements. I tried it and .schema throws an exception as an invalid sqlite statement.